# expected token 'end of statement block', got '='

Tags: django, jinja2

I am trying to assign value to a dictionary in Jinja2 and its not working properly and showing error.

> expected token 'end of statement block', got '='

**My Code:**

```
 {% set sequence = ['a1', 'b1']%}           
 {% set dic = {} %}
            {% for filter in search_result.filters %}
                {% for seq_key in sequence %}
                    {% if seq_key == filter.key %}
                         {# here i wish to create a dictionary where key= seq_key and value = filter_object#}
                            {% do dic[seq_key]=filter %}
                            
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `do` statement takes only an expression, not a statement like an assignment. Since Jinja2 does not directly support assigning to a dict by key, you can call the dict's `update` method with a singleton dict containing the new key-value mapping instead.

Change:

```
{% do dic[seq_key]=filter %}
```

to:

```
{% do dic.update({seq_key: filter}) %}
```